# How to write * (asterisk) when adding any comment?

Tags: support, comments, markdown

Few days ago I was trying to put some comment on XML namespace issue and I wanted to put `*:element-name` at the comment. But after submission it deleted asterisk and change it to `:element-name`. Is there any other way to put this character in comment? or Is this any bug?

Comment: `*:element-name` and *:element-name where is the issue???

Comment: Maybe add it as `code` like `*:element-name` and not *:element-name. After seeing my own comment, it looks like that * is being displayed in both cases.

Comment: I don't think there is any issue with using asterisk *:element-name

Comment: Probably triggered *italics* `*italics*` because of surrounding stuff.

Comment: I'm guessing * only triggers *italics* when surrounded by white space * unlike these *  Not sure why yours were **removed** though.

Comment: Was it something like this: *:game/*:title (`*:game/*:title`) that you tried to write?

Comment: Yes, you are right Mat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular case it sounds like you might have been better off using code formatting anyway (i.e. `` `*:example` ``), but that aside, you can escape any Markdown formatting character like the asterisk by putting a backslash in front:

```
\*:example
```

Comment: For \*:example, this is not italicized*

Comment: But this *:example is*